# Pagination in angular material from data fetched from an api

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material2

I get a list of 100+ users fetched from an api. Now I would like to implement that data in the angular material table.

Is it possible in the frontend that i display only 10 users in pageSize and have pagination. I tried but it displays all available users eventhough I have pagination module implemented.

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

In the typescript code, i get the list from the parent component.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() users;

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'id'];
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.users);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your `.ts` file?

Comment: @mintquan I have updated the code.. I get the list from the parent component. So i use it on the `ngOnChanges` to get the list of data.

Comment: try in after view Init hook `ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }`

Comment: @Vikas it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I made it work. 
Putting the paginator in `ngOnChanges`

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.users);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Really you needn't use ngOnChanges, but if you use, you need asign datasource.paginator in ngOnChanges **too**.

Also, take account if the paginator is visible or not when you asign to your datasource.

If you use in ngOnInit you need use static:true

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator,{static:true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

but remember that, in that case the paginator can not be under a *ngIf, else use ngAfterViewInit

BTW, if you has access to the API or the paginator is on server -not in frontend, you can take a look to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274)