# Connect method DataSource is not emitting all paginated rows for MatTable

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use the DataSource interface to update MatTableData, using server-side pagination.

```
<div>

  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortDisableClear>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-200 th-center"> Type</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-200 th-center"> {{v.type}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-200 th-center"> Title</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-200 th-center"> {{v.title}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-200 th-center"> Status</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-200 th-center"> {{v.status}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="url">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-200 th-center"> Url</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-200 th-center"> {{v.url}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="host">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-250 th-center"> Host </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-250 th-center"> {{v.host}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ipv4">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-250 th-center"> Ipv4 </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-250 th-center"> {{v.ipv4}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="w-250 th-center"> Category 
    </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v" class="w-250 th-center"> {{v.category}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let v"> {{v.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-header-row>

    <mat-row class="element-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns();">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator [length]="total" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">

  </mat-paginator>

</div>



@Component({
  selector: 'kt-vulnerability-list',
  templateUrl: './vulnerability-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vulnerability-list.component.scss']
})
export class VulnerabilityListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  displayColumns;
  dataSource: VulnerabilityDataSource
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  total = 1172;

  constructor(private globalEntityStore: GlobalEntityStore,
              private vulnerabilityDataService: VulnerabilityDataService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // const store$ = this.globalEntityStore.state$;

    const tableConfig = new VulnerabilityTableConfig();
    this.displayColumns = tableConfig.configClient;

    this.dataSource = new VulnerabilityDataSource(this.vulnerabilityDataService);

    this.dataSource.loadVulns('ERA Home Security Ltd', '', 'asc', 0, 1);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sort.sortChange
      .subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        tap(() => this.loadVulnsPage()),
        tap( () => {
          this.total -= this.paginator.pageSize;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  loadVulnsPage() {
    this.dataSource.loadVulns(
      'ERA Home Security Ltd',
      '',
      'asc',
      this.paginator.pageIndex,
      this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  getDisplayedColumns() {
    return this.displayColumns
      .filter(cd => !cd.hidden)
      .map(cd => cd.name);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }
```

```
export class VulnerabilityDataSource implements DataSource<Vulnerability> {

  private vulnerabilitySubject = new BehaviorSubject<Vulnerability[]>([]);
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private vulnerabilityDataService: VulnerabilityDataService) {
    this.vulnerabilitySubject.subscribe(res => console.log('vulnerability subject emiiting ', res))
  }

  public thing() {
    return this.vulnerabilitySubject.asObservable()
  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Vulnerability[]> {
    console.log('connect called');
    return this.vulnerabilitySubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.vulnerabilitySubject.complete();
  }

  loadVulns(clientName: string, filter = '',
            sortDirection = 'asc', pageIndex = 0, pageSize = 3) {

    this.vulnerabilityDataService.fetchVulnerabilities(clientName, filter, sortDirection,
      pageIndex, pageSize)
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => of([])),
        map(res => {
          return new JsonConvert().deserializeArray(res, Vulnerability);
        })
      ).subscribe(v => {

      this.vulnerabilitySubject.next(v);
    });

  }
}
```

The problem is the **Connect()** is not updating **dataSource** in my component.
It does render 2 pages, the third page is not rendered in the table.

I can see the HTTP calls and **this.vulnerabilitySubject.next(v);** emitting the next set of values. However, the connect method breaks for some reason and does not update the table beyond after page 2.

Any ideas from anyone? I can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your VulnerabilityDataSource, has not property `data` nor `filter` nor `sort`...

Really I can't imagine what do you want to reach with your code. If the only you want a mat-table with filter, sort and pagination in server, you can get it only subscribing to filter.valuesChange, paginator.page and sort.sortChange

Imagine you has a service with two functions

```
 //return and observable with the length of the data
getLength(filter:string)

//return an observable of an array with the data filtered, ordered and take account
//page and pageSize
getData(page:number,
        pageSize:number,
        filter:string,
        sortField:string,
        sortDirection:string)
```

In ngAfterViewInit you can has some like

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const getLength = this.filter.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      debounceTime(200),
      switchMap((res: string) => this.dataService.getLength(res)),
      tap((res: number) => {
        this.paginator.firstPage();
        this.total = res;
      })
    );
    const sort = this.sort.sortChange.pipe(
      tap(() => this.paginator.firstPage())
    );
    merge(getLength, sort, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(_ => (this.isLoadingResults = true)),
        switchMap(res => {
          return this.dataService.getData(
            this.paginator.pageIndex,
            this.paginator.pageSize,
            this.filter.value,
            this.sort.active,
            this.sort.direction
          );
        }),
        tap(_ => (this.isLoadingResults = false))
      )
      .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
        this.dataSource = res;
      });
  }
```

where

```
  filter = new FormControl();
  isLoadingResults = false;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

See that we merge trhee observables: when the formControl that make of "filter" change the value, when change the pagine in paginator and when sort the data

We use `pipe(tap)` to send to the first page in the last two cases. This is [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1y7mgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts), I hope this can help you

Comment: this is amazing! Thank you so much. I am going to try and implement this.