# Angular Mat table Pagination Page index with Http request

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular-material, mat-table

I have an API where I fetch based on the Page number, how can I send table page index that changes on next and previous buttons  to this API  please note that I created a shared table

```
 @Input() columns: Column[] = [];
 @Input()rows!: Row<T>[];

 @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) matSort!: MatSort;
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) matPaginator!: MatPaginator;
 @Input() isPageable = false;
 @Input() paginationSizes: number[] = [5, 10, 15];
 @Input() defaultPageSize = this.paginationSizes[1];
 pageNo = 0;
 @Input() PageIndex = 0;
 public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Row<T>>();
 public columnNames: string[] = []


 constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataSource.data = this.rows;
  this.columnNames = this.columns.map((column) => column.name.toString());
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.matPaginator;}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.matPaginator;}
 
  pageEvents(event: any) {
  console.log("PageIndex " + "=" + event.pageIndex);
  if (event.pageIndex > this.pageNo) {
  this.PageIndex = event.pageIndex
  console.log(this.PageIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need subscribe to paginator.page

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.paginator.page.subscribe(res=>{
      //res is an object like
      {length:...,pageIndex:..,pageSize:...,previousPageIndex:..}
    })
  }
```

NOTE: If you want a complex example with filter/sorted and paginator you can take a look to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274)