# How to load jquery data table effeciently in angular 9 which contain 10 million record from asp.net core and mssql?

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core, datatables

I am working in Angular 9+, asp.net core for the backend and MSSQL server.
I need to show 10 million records in the jquery data table with search, sorting, paging enabled.

I am not able to search, if I pass the page number starts to count like 1000 to 2000 records from API and show it.

If I try to access all records from DB to web API and table it takes more than 5 mins.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274 you has a table with filter, sorting and pagination that makes request using mat-table. (you can use to inspiration if you don't want use material) NOTE: remove the "jquery" in your question

Comment: _"10 million records in the jquery data table"_: Use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). It is useful "when dealing with many thousands or millions of data rows". Various [examples](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html).

Comment: Please do not post comments such as "_I am waiting_". This is a community of volunteers. If you have not already done so, you can also take the [tour] and read [ask].