# Angular Table CDK with remote source

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to figure out how to populate my table data source from a remote source.

I've used the [material schematic to add the table](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#table-schematic) which has resulted in a datasource scaffold that looks like this:

```
export class ExampleTableDataSource extends DataSource<ExampleTableItem> {
  data: ExampleTableItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  sort: MatSort | undefined;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<ExampleTableItem[]> {
    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
      // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
      // stream for the data-table to consume.
      return merge(observableOf(this.data), this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange)
        .pipe(map(() => {
          return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data ]));
        }));
    } else {
      throw Error('Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.');
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect(): void {}

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: ExampleTableItem[]): ExampleTableItem[] {
    if (this.paginator) {
      const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: ExampleTableItem[]): ExampleTableItem[] {
    if (!this.sort || !this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort?.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort?.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Reading through the material it indicates that I should be using the connect() function to retrieve the data from the remote source.

So I created a dummy service that points to local instance of API server:

```
const url = 'https://localhost:44391/api/Data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExampleService {
  EXAMPLE_DATA: ExampleModel[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(value: ExampleModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<ExampleModel>(url, value);
  }

  getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url);
  }
}
```

Now for the life of me I don't understand how do I use the connect function to get the said that from the remote source.

I've seen examples where connect() was bypassed, some extended it to use BehaviourSubject but it all seems like workarounds.

What would be the proper way to connect those two things up for me to be able to get data from remote service and display it in the table.

Comment: a datasource of a mat-table can be an Array, an Observable or a MatDataSource. I imagine, that you need use "conect()" as data source: `<table mat-table [dataSource]="conect()" matSort>`. BTW If you want an example make it "manually", you can see this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274