# Calling a method from an Angular view only once

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material

I have built a table from angular materials. I have an object called "matricula" and in the first column I print the property matricula.matricula from a list of matriculas. In the second column I want to print some data I get calling a method from that matricula.matricula. I have my method defined in my Typescrypt document but as it works with a webservice, I only want to call the method for the objects that are shown at each moment (which variates as I have a paginator). I have tried calling the method from the view using {{method}}, but as Angular views work on real time, the method is being called all the time and the project crashes.

How could I do the call only once for each object matricula? I am sure it must be possible but I have no idea which tool or method I should use.

Here is the code from the view:

```
            <ng-container matColumnDef="matricula" style="flex: 0 0 10%;" >
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Matrícula </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let matricula"height=70px> {{matricula.matricula}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="posicion" style="flex: 0 0 50%;">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ubicación </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let matricula" height=70px> {{method(matricula.matricula)}} </td>
            </ng-container>

       

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="mostrarColumnas"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let matricula; columns: mostrarColumnas;"></tr>
        </table>
```

Edit: Here is the code from the method:

```
    let matricula : MatriculaBuscada = {
      action : "ultima_posicion",
      matricula : placa
    }
    this.posicionService.posicion(matricula).subscribe(datos => {
    return datos;});
    console.log('método getDatos')
  }
```

The posicionService only calls a webservice which sends back a Json that is already mapped.

Comment: use the [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

Comment: I have tried it as OnInit only initializes once, but I'm not sure about how it could solve my problem. I thought about calling the method for each displayed element and saving them in an array. The problem is that once I have done this, the only idea I have for displaying the array is a loop method wich prints the first element of the array and deletes it. This method would be called from the view, so the problem with it is that even if the array is empty, the loop will be working to the infinite.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with Angular templates being "real time". Angular should only re-render the component (thus recall the method) when the change detection cycle found a hit.

Comment: Maybe I am missunderstanding the reason why the method is called non-stop but the point is that I need it to only be called once.

Comment: The function gets called for each change detection cycle. Please show how the `method()` function is implemented. Probably it could be moved to a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

Comment: Added. Thank you

Comment: It is not a good idea to subscribe to a stream inside a method you call from the template, and as the method is written now it doesn't even have a return value? Subscriptions work asynchronously, so the part `return datos` will not be executed before the method returns. Also it will effectively do nothing, because you do not store the value from datos anywhere.

Comment: From where do you get the (paginated) list of matriculas? If you're dealing with an observable which emits the collection of matriculas for the current page (e.g. matriculas 0-10), you can probably use rxjs to fetch this additional data for those matriculas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not "paginate" your API (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274)), I imagine that the best bet is subscribe to the matPaginator.changes.

I imagine you has a service with two functions: getAllData -that return the data incomplete- and getData(id) -that return the auxiliar data of one item

You can has in ngAfterViewInit some like: -I used in the e.g. the tipical material table with the periodic elements

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //I use the setTimeout for avoid
    // the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"
    setTimeout(()=>{
      //simple get the data, getAllData simply return an array os "positions"
      this.dataService.getAllData().pipe(
        map((res: any[]) => {
          //create an object with all the properties necesary
          return res.map((x) => ({
            position: x,  //<--this is the only I get
            name: null,   //the rest properties I put as null
            weight: 0,
            symbol: null,
            yet: false,  //<--add this new property
          }));
        })
      ).subscribe((res:any[])=>{
        this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(res)
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.initPaginator()  //<--this is the "key"
      });
  
    })
  }
  initPaginator(){
    //I subscribe to paginator.page
    //happens always you change the page or the page size
    this.paginator.page.pipe(
      startWith(1),
      ).subscribe((_) => {

      //get the data that really is showed
      //and filter only I not loaded before
      const data = this.dataSource.filteredData
        .slice(
          this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize,
          (this.paginator.pageIndex + 1) * this.paginator.pageSize
        )
        .filter((x: any) => !x.yet);

      //if there're data
      if (data.length) {
        this.isLoadingResults=true;
        //create a forkJoin -and array of Observables-
        //e.g. at first is a forkJoin of the array:
        //[this.dataService.getData(1),
        //   this.dataService.getData(2),
        //   ...]
        forkJoin(
          data.map((x: any) => this.dataService.getData(x.position))
        ).subscribe((res: any[]) => {

          //in subscribe, try to find the data
          res.forEach((x) => {
            let item = this.dataSource.data.find(
              (d: any) => (d.position == x.position)
            );
            //and put the properties I received
            if (item) {
              item.name=x.name;
              item.weight=x.weight;
              item.symbol=x.symbol;
              item.yet=true;
            }
          });

          this.isLoadingResults=false
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

You can see [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1y7mgx-egahh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts)