# Angular grid with server side filtering, sorting and pagination?

Tags: c#, angular, ag-grid, server-side-rendering, paging

I want to implement Angular grid with server side pagination, filtering and sorting> Ag grid provide these feature in enterprise edition only. Is there any other grid which I can use free on production environment.

Comment: Using mat-table, check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274). You can use also ng-bootstrap table, see the [last example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples)

Comment: @Eliseo I am looking for column level filtering done by server side

Comment: So what exactly is stopping you from implementing this? What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I used ng prime grid now and it is working. Thanks