# How to filter data with pagination - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a filter that searches any user that is in a list, even the list coming directly paged from the backend by the endpoint:

```js
private readonly apiUser= '/api/users';

listPageUsers( page:any, size:number): Observable<Page>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Page>(`${this.apiUser}?size=${size}&page=${page}&sort=firstName,asc`).pipe()
  }
```

And the Interface is:

```js
export interface Usuario {
  id:string;
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  username: string
  email: string
  role: Role
  branch: Branch
  
}

export interface Role {
  id: number
  //authority:string
}

export interface Branch {
  id: number
  //name:string
}


export interface Page {
  content: Usuario[],
  pageable: {
      sort: {
          empty: boolean,
          sorted: boolean,
          unsorted: boolean
      },
      offset: number,
      pageSize: number,
      pageNumber: number,
      unpaged: boolean,
      paged: boolean
  },
  last: boolean,
  totalPages: number,
  totalElements: number,
  size: number,
  number: number,
  sort: {
      empty: boolean,
      sorted: boolean,
      unsorted: boolean
  },
  numberOfElements: number,
  first: boolean,
  empty: boolean
}
```

the paginated list of users works perfectly.
I created a simple filter, but this filter can only get users from the first page, not all pages.
Thats the filter that I created, HTML:

```html
 <mat-form-field class="matfield" appearance="outline">
<input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterValue" >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-table [dataSource]="usuarios | filter: filterValue">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nome </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.firstName }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sobrenome</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.lastName }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.username }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>E-mail</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.email }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Papel</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.role.authority }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="branch">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Filial</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.branch.name }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="lastAccountActivity">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Último acesso</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.lastAccountActivity | date:'short':'-0300':'pt'}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="action-column">
        <button
          mat-mini-fab
          color="accent"
          title="Adicionar um Usuário"
          (click)="onAdd()"
          class="action-column-header"
        >
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-header-cell>

      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="action-column">


        <button button mat-icon-button class="botao-enviar" title="Gerar Nova Senha"
          (click)="onSend(element)">
          <mat-icon>outgoing_mail</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <button mat-icon-button class="botao-editar" title="Editar Usuário"
          (click)="onEdit(element)">

          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>


      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
<mat-paginator
  #paginator
  [length]="length"
  [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"
  (page)="pageNavigations($event)"
  showFirstLastButtons
  aria-label="Selecione a Página"
>
</mat-paginator>
```

in my component I just created a simple variable of type string:

```js
filterValue: string = '';
```

the backend guy said that with the endpoint: '/api/users?search='
I could pull all the users from the database, but even creating a service that did that, it didn't solve it
Service that I created:

```js
  listUserFilter(filter: any):Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.apiUser}?search=${filter}`);
  }
```

I don't know what else to do

Comment: check this  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274)