# How can I use an Angular DataSource with ngBootstrap?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

As it said in their doc:

> For most real-world applications, providing the table a DataSource instance will be the best way to manage data. The DataSource is meant to serve as a place to encapsulate any sorting, filtering, pagination, and data retrieval logic specific to the application.

But, in that doc, they are using Angular Material. As an old dev that using PHP as daily language, also have 8 years experience using Bootstrap(v2, v3, v4, v5), I want still use the Table of bootstrap implementation for reduce learning curve. So I decide to use [Ng Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

Are there any references or examples about this?

Comment: In [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274) there're a "mat-table" with filter, order and pagination. It's the same with a simple table and a ngb-paginator. You create an observable that take account the order, filter and page and call to an API (you can use pipeAsync)

Comment: It's not a good idea mixing material and ng-boostrap. If you're using ng-bootstrap, use the tables and follow [the guides and examples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/overview#examples) in the docs for pagination, sort, filter, service... Really are two very diferent concepts related to a table.